# dynamically embedded google analytics from widget

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

```
var script2 = document.createElement( 'script' );
script2.value = "var _gaq = _gaq || [];_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-1']);_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'http://www.widget.devserver2012.com']);_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]); _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);(function() {var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})()";

$('head').prepend(script2);
```

I am using this code to embed Google Analytics in the document head from a javascript widget, users will be embedding on their page.  But is Google Analytics is not receiving data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `script2.text = "..."` or `script2.innerHTML = "..."` instead of `script2.value = "..."`.

Here's a jsfiddle that tests using all three assignments with the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/7nsGp/

```
var script2 = document.createElement( 'script' );
script2.value = 'alert("assign value worked");';
$('head').prepend(script2);

var script1 = document.createElement( 'script' );
script1.text = 'alert("assign text worked");';
$('head').prepend(script1); 

var script0 = document.createElement( 'script' );
script0.innerHTML = 'alert("assign innerHTML worked");';
$('head').prepend(script0);
```

On both Chrome and Firefox, assigned either `.text` or `.innerHTML`, but not `.value`.

Suggestion: Verify that your script snippet is executing by appending an `alert('script ran')` to the end of your script text during testing.

```
script2.value = "var _gaq = _gaq || []; ... ; alert('script ran');";
```

Comment: this answer makes no sense. it would have to be alert('script2.text') to alert the value otherwise it would just alert "DOM object."  I am appending a facebook snippet the same way using .value and it works.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what browser you're using, but assigning script content to a script element using `.value` doesn't seem to work in Chrome or Firefox. I updated my answer with a test script & alert example.